# 3D Surf/Mesh Plot from a Single Line in csv File? Pgfplots preferably

Tags: pgfplots, 3d, csv

I have done a range of experiments, each using 9 sensors. The sensors are physically aligned in 3 by 3, and I would like to also show the data in a mesh or surface plot like this. However, I get the data in a csv file where each row is one experiment with the resulting sensor values, like the following:

```
Experiment, S0, S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8
Test1, 129.0, 82.6, 61.0, 110.6, 113.7, 95.9, 51.9, 98.1, 169.1
Test2, 82.5, 58.5, 51.8, 65.1, 84.1, 80.0, 44.6, 75.5, 88.5
```

As I want to plot quite a lot of them, I would prefer not to manually need to realign data or to write a script that does.

I already tried using different options but can't figure out what would be the right way to approach it.

This is my MWE for having a 2D plot of this data:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Experiment, S0, S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8
Test1, 129.0, 82.6, 61.0, 110.6, 113.7, 95.9, 51.9, 98.1, 169.1
Test2, 82.5, 58.5, 51.8, 65.1, 84.1, 80.0, 44.6, 75.5, 88.5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}\rawtable
\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=Experiment]\data{\rawtable}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot[mark=*,blue] table [x expr=\coordindex, y=Test1, col sep=comma] {\data};
\addplot[mark=*,red] table [x expr=\coordindex, y=Test2, col sep=comma] {\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution myself, but think that it might be tricky to find, so I share. I am using `x expr` and `y expr` to compute the coordinates. Other suggestions are still welcome!

Here see the MWE for 3D plots, only changing the two `\addplot` lines to some `\addplot3` lines was sufficient.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Experiment, S0, S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8
Test1, 129.0, 82.6, 61.0, 110.6, 113.7, 95.9, 51.9, 98.1, 169.1
Test2, 82.5, 58.5, 51.8, 65.1, 84.1, 80.0, 44.6, 75.5, 88.5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}\rawtable
\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=Experiment]\data{\rawtable}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot3[mesh,mark=*,blue] table [x expr={int(mod(\coordindex,3))}, y expr={int(\coordindex / 3)}, z=Test1, col sep=comma] {\data};
\addplot3[mesh,mark=*,red] table [x expr={int(mod(\coordindex,3))}, y expr={int(\coordindex / 3)}, z=Test2, col sep=comma] {\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```